# Using a naked-domain-redirect service breaks email on my domain

Tags: dns

I am using wwwizer.com/ as a naked domain redirect. This is working perfectly, but I have since noticed that email to the domain is being sent to the wwwizer address

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. 
[(0) myDomain.co.uk. [174.129.25.170]:25: socket error]
```

So I obviously have something set up incorrectly.
Any ideas? do I need to supply any more info?
cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this problem by removing the naked domain redirect service from the apex A record, and used a higher level redirect that pointed all incoming naked http requests to the www subdomain, instead of all traffic.